# Images not showing after moving site (but path id OK)

Tags: images

I moved (actually copied) a WordPress site (http://inglesen100dias.com/) to a new server and domain (http://blog.inglesen100dias.com/).

I followed the process described on [Wordpress' website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server) and also used a [search and replace script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) as recommended there to fix the path of the images, so they use the new URL of the site.

Everything seems fine except the images, which they don't show (as you can see if you click in both links above). But looking at the path of the images, it seems to be fine, and even if I copy that path and paste it in the browser the image shows fine, but it doesn't when looking at the website.

I've also removed the .htaccess file but nothing is working.

Does anyone have ideas how I can get the images to work?

Comment: Did you ftp in and verify that the images are actually there?

Comment: @AndrewBartel yes, I forgot to mention that, but as I said, if I copy the path of those images to the browser's address bar and access it, I can see the image, so it's not a problem of the images not being in the correct place, or the paths used by wordpress (they are exactly the same only adding the "blog." particle)

Comment: I got a "Could not open the lockfile for writing an image." timthumb error when trying to directly access the images.  Can you install this plugin and run it?  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/timthumb-vulnerability-scanner/  Also, what is the permissions for your timthumb cache folder?

Comment: I installed that plugin and ran it, it upgraded the timthumb.php file, but the images still don't show. Where's the timthumb cache folder? All the folders I can see have 755 permissions. How did you get that error? What I meant by directly accessing the images was using the file path (without calling any function). For example, for the first post, it would be http://blog.inglesen100dias.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1072482_79445869.jpg, which means that the files are actually in their place, so the problem must come from somewhere else... Any ideas?

Comment: Albert, your site is using the timthumb script to handle image resizing on the fly.  There is an issue with that.  A common solution during my googling was to set the permissions of the cache folder within the timthumb directory to 777, but I can't see why that would be necessary.  I just opened your blog site and it looks like it's working..?  Has your issue been resolved?  You should post your solution as an answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post the answer to my problem, which I got thanks to the links provided by Jesse. What I did was to delete the index.html and .touch files form the cache folder where the tinthumb.php file is located. After that it all worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I get when trying to view any image directly:

> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Utime failed: Permission denied in
>   /home/columbia/public_html/wordpress/inglesen100dias/wp-content/themes/motionpicture/functions/timthumb.php
>   on line 200
>
> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Utime failed: Permission denied in
>   /home/columbia/public_html/wordpress/inglesen100dias/wp-content/themes/motionpicture/functions/timthumb.php
>   on line 469
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/columbia/public_html/wordpress/inglesen100dias/wp-content/themes/motionpicture/functions/timthumb.php:200)
>   in
>   /home/columbia/public_html/wordpress/inglesen100dias/wp-content/themes/motionpicture/functions/timthumb.php
>   on line 418 A TimThumb error has occured
>
> The following error(s) occured: Could not create the index.html file -
>   to fix this create an empty file named index.html file in the cache
>   directory. Could not create cache clean timestamp file.
>
> Query String :
>   `src=http://blog.inglesen100dias.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1072482_79445869.jpg&w=195&h=120&zc=1&f=`
>   TimThumb version : 2.8.11

A quick search found these two results:

- [Wordpress Error: A TimThumb error has occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833697/wordpress-error-a-timthumb-error-has-occured)
- [Timthumb can't show image after it's uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396991/timthumb-cant-show-image-after-its-uploaded)

Comment: Yep, found the solution! The trick was to delete the index.html and .touch files from the cache folder where the timthumb.php file is

Comment: May I ask you to add a readable solution, not just two links?